# Error Reading JSON with Rascal with multiple constructors

Tags: json, rascal

The following code:

```
import lang::json::IO;

data Field = field(map[str, str]);
data Block = null() 
            | block(str \type)
            | block(str \type, str id)
            | block(str \type, Block next)
            | block(str \type, Field field, Input input, Block next);
data Input  = input(map[str, Block]);

writeJSON(|file:///rascal/block.json|, block("type","sdlkfjl"));
readJSON(#Block, |file:///rascal/block.json|);
```

Gives an error:

```
rascal>readJSON(#Block, |file:///rascal/block.json|);
|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(976,2999,<32,0>,<60,179>): IO("Overloading of constructor names is not supported 
(Block):$.block")
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(976,2999,<32,0>,<60,179>))
        at readJSON(|std:///lang/json/IO.rsc|(3968,5,<60,172>,<60,177>)ok
rascal>
```

As is shown in the code; my block have some optional fields. What options do I have to write and read to JSON?

Comment: The issue is tracked via: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1683